# Format data set as expected by endpoint request

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to format data that I send to an endpoint. Currently the endpoint expects a certain format but the data that I am sending does not match that entirely. The data I am sending has extra brackets. Please see my code below versus what it expected.

*What I am sending*

```
[
    [
        {
            "corporateId": "97765c76-19c3-48b5-8183-d450e72e8f23",
            "selectedMAP": [
                {
                    "mapId": 53,
                    "mapName": "Discovery",
                    "active": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "optionId": 81,
                            "optionName": "Keycare",
                            "memberAmount": 1000,
                            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
                            "childDependantAmount": 500,
                            "active": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "mapId": 54,
                    "mapName": "Bestmed",
                    "active": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "optionId": 83,
                            "optionName": "Beat 1",
                            "memberAmount": 1000,
                            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
                            "childDependantAmount": 500,
                            "active": true
                        },
                        {
                            "optionId": 84,
                            "optionName": "Beat 2",
                            "memberAmount": 2000,
                            "adultDependantAmount": 1000,
                            "childDependantAmount": 1000,
                            "active": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    {
        "gapCoverProviders": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "a",
                "isActive": true,
                "gapCoverOptions": [
                    {
                        "id": 0,
                        "name": "b",
                        "optionPrice": 111,
                        "isActive": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

*What is expected*

```
{
  "corporateId": "string",
  "active": true,
  "selectedMAP": [
    {
      "mapId": 0,
      "mapName": "string",
      "active": true,
      "options": [
        {
          "optionId": 0,
          "optionName": "string",
          "memberAmount": 0,
          "adultDependantAmount": 0,
          "childDependantAmount": 0,
          "active": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gapCoverProviders": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "isActive": true,
      "gapCoverOptions": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string",
          "isActive": true,
          "optionPrice": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I build the structure that is being posted as follows. I have 2 models which I then combine into 1 data set.

*model 1*

```
export class CompanyMedicalAidProvider {
  corporateId: string;
  active: boolean = true;
  selectedMAP: Array<SelectedMap>;
}
```

*model 2*

```
export class CompanyGapCoverProvider {
  gapCoverProviders: Array<GapCoverProviders>;
}
```

*data that gets posted*

```
data = [this.companyMedicalAidProvider, this.companyGapCoverProvider];
```

Any ideas how i can go about changing the structure? I am stuck on this part.

Comment: Looks like you are missing certain fields as well. For the [ ] just reference it via [0]

Comment: pass data[0] instead of data in the post request

Comment: @SHenry the `active` field is not necessary

Comment: how do you get the structure you have? you're building it or getting it from somewhere?

Comment: @MaxG I am building it from 2 models which I then combine into 1 model. I will show them in the question

Comment: @ShlokNangia passing data[0] removed the entire `gapCoverProviders` section. I have updated the question to give more info on how the structure is built up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new Data in required format like this

```js
var data = [
    [
        {
            "corporateId": "97765c76-19c3-48b5-8183-d450e72e8f23",
            "selectedMAP": [
                {
                    "mapId": 53,
                    "mapName": "Discovery",
                    "active": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "optionId": 81,
                            "optionName": "Keycare",
                            "memberAmount": 1000,
                            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
                            "childDependantAmount": 500,
                            "active": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "mapId": 54,
                    "mapName": "Bestmed",
                    "active": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "optionId": 83,
                            "optionName": "Beat 1",
                            "memberAmount": 1000,
                            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
                            "childDependantAmount": 500,
                            "active": true
                        },
                        {
                            "optionId": 84,
                            "optionName": "Beat 2",
                            "memberAmount": 2000,
                            "adultDependantAmount": 1000,
                            "childDependantAmount": 1000,
                            "active": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    {
        "gapCoverProviders": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "a",
                "isActive": true,
                "gapCoverOptions": [
                    {
                        "id": 0,
                        "name": "b",
                        "optionPrice": 111,
                        "isActive": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

var newData = data[0][0]
newData['gapCoverProviders'] = data[1]['gapCoverProviders'];
console.log(newData)
```